# Create and render flexbox columns in tinymce?

Tags: tinymce

Is there a way to create and render columns in tinymce? eg I'd like to somehow insert

```
<div style={display:flex;}>
<div style={flex:50%;}>
<h2>Hello Earth!</h2>
</div>
<div style={flex:50%;}>
<h2>Hello Mars!</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the brackets but you can create a template instead with classes

example

```
templates: [
    {"title":"2 rows","description":"Insert, 2 rows with the same width","content":"<article class=\"cmsblock\"><div class=\"col span_6\"><h2>Row 1</h2><p>row 1</p></div><div class=\"col span_6\"><h2>Row 2</h2><p>row 2</p></div></article><div class=\"clear\">&nbsp;</div><p></p>"},
    {"title":"3 rows","description":"Insert, 3 rows with the same width","content":"<article class=\"cmsblock\"><div class=\"col span_4\"><h2>Row 1</h2><p>row 1</p></div><div class=\"col span_4\"><h2>Row 2</h2><p>row 2</p></div><div class=\"col span_4\"><h2>Row 3</h2><p>row 3</p></div></article><div class=\"clear\">&nbsp;</div><p></p>"}
],
```